# PHP Array key name

Tags: php, arrays

For a project i found out i have to start using array intersect.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

There i found this code which explains what the function does:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

The output is what confuses me.

```
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

What do `a` and `0` mean in this case?

Shouldn't it be 0 1 why does it start with a and then goes to 0.

Comment: You already link to the answer of your question: *"array_intersect() returns an array containing all the values of array1 that are present in all the arguments. **Note that keys are preserved.**"*

Comment: What is confusing you is the fact that those are not "arrays" - they're *dictionaries*. $array1 is [ a => green, 0 => red, 1 => blue ], has two numeric automatic keys and one text key. Use of array_intersect in this scenario *is* possible, but... IMHO, **to be carefully avoided**.

Comment: The output is, all of the values in `$array1` that are present in `$array2`. Both "green" and "red" are found, so those keys from `$array1` are preserved and the other values discarded.

Comment: To extend the clarification, the reason why you see "a" is because it comes from the first array passed to `array_intersect`, if you change the order `array_intersect($array2, $array1)` ...you will see `Array ( [b] => green [1] => red )` instead

Comment: if you don't keep the key, use array_values()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

First of all we must write those dictionaries as they really are; the form above is "condensed", with implicit numeric keys.

```
$array1 is a: green, 0: red, 1: blue
$array2 is b: green, 0: yellow, 1: red
```

Now `array_intersect` checks what **values** are common. They are green, and red. The corresponding **items** from array1 are taken:

```
a: green
0: red
```

and so you have two keys, 'a' and 0, mapped to green and red respectively.

At this point I'll add that **mixing numeric and non-numeric keys is a recipe for disaster**, unless you're incredibly careful about what you're doing; lots of PHP functions will not preserve keys and renumber the values converting dictionaries to arrays.

And as you have seen, it's not immediate to tell an array from a dictionary. To add to the risk, JSON encoding is completely different for the two, so a tiny change in a structure might make a Web service conversation to abruptly collapse.

## JSON

This is my favourite parlor trick.

```
$arr = array( 'Hello', 'World' );
```

This JSON-encodes, as you would expect, to:

```
[ 'Hello', 'World' ]
```

Let's say I delete the last element and re-JSON:

```
[ 'Hello' ]
```

But let's say I delete an element **that is not the last**. What does PHP do? It removes the element and the key, *but does not renumber the array*. The array has now a *hole*. And arrays don't have holes -- *dictionaries* do.

So this is now a **dictionary**. And in JSON it suddenly becomes:

```
{ "1": "World" }
```

Which means that **this example code is subtly bugged**:

```
$arr = functionReturningArrayOfElements();

if (-1 != $killThisElement) {
    unset($arr[$killThisElement]);
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode($arr));
```

When `$killThisElement` is the very last entry ($count($arr)-1), then the JSON will be encoded as an array. Otherwise, it will be encoded as a dictionary.

Before returning, I need to be sure of what I return:

```
$arr = array_values($arr); // This renumbers the keys, forcing it to always be an array
```

or

```
$arr['count'] = count($arr);
// This adds a non-numeric key, forcing $arr to always be a dictionary.
// The extra key is called 'count' just so it makes sense, but it is also
// a BAD IDEA, since it encourages to loop through the object instead of
// using the proper Javascript Object methods. A better choice from this
// point of view would be
$arr['comment'] = 'This is a dictionary.';
```

Comment: Also helpful to know since I will be using this with json encoding

Comment: I've added some JSON considerations that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

> - The `array_intersect()` function compares the values of two (or more) arrays, and returns the matches.
> - This function compares the values of two or more arrays, and return an array that contains the entries from `array1` that are present in `array2`, `array3`, etc.

So in your case, the array has elements with and without keys, so if we compare arrays, we find that `$array2` has `green` and `red` elements which are present in `$array1`, so if you print the array using `print_r()`, it will out put the array with custom & preserved keys (preserved in case of no key is assigned).

> See more about [array_intersect()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp)

So if you try to print `$array1`, it would be like:

```
array:3 [
  "b" => "green"
  0 => "yellow"
  1 => "red"
]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For representation `$array1` is built like this.

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", 0 => "red", 1 => "blue");
```

So the fact that `array_intersect` maintains keys both these key:value pairs with sustain

```
"a" => "green", 0 => "red"
```